# Deleted cookies in UIWebView returning after quitting and restarting the app

Tags: iphone, cookies, uiwebview

I have multiple UIWebViews in my app to log into an ASP.NET web site. I can log in to the site  ok. However if I log out of the web site and quit and restart the app, it appears to still have the cookies and I am still logged in. It I don't quit the app, the cookies are gone and the site does not know who I am after I log out.

I have tried removing cookies in the app itself using the following code:

```
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *httpCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *httpCookie in [httpCookieStorage cookies])
    {
        [httpCookieStorage deleteCookie:httpCookie];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I have seen that works for some but doesn't appear to make a different after quitting the app.